# Заполнение двумерного массива через пробел

Tags: c#, строки

Требуется заполнить двумерный массив через пробел. Уже есть вот такой код:

```
static void Zapolnenie(int[,] arr)

    {
        string arrs;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива через пробел");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            arrs = Console.ReadLine();
            arrs.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
                arr[i, j] = int.Parse(arrs[j]);
        }
    }
```

Среда пишет, что "не удается преобразовать из char в string". Как это исправить?

Comment: `arrs.Split` возвращает в никуда результат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `Split` разбивает строку по разделителю и возвращает массив, который вы никуда не сохраняете и продолжаете работать с исходной строкой `arrs`. А обращение к строке по индексу возвращает вам символ (char), в то время как `int.Parse` ожидает строку.

Правильно будет так:

```
var str = "77 88 99";
var items = str.Split(' ');
var firstItem = int.Parse(items[0]);
```

---

В вашем методе это будет выглядеть так:

```
static void Zapolnenie(int[,] arr)
{   
    string arrs;
    Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива через пробел");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        arrs = Console.ReadLine();
        var items = arrs.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            arr[i, j] = int.Parse(items[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: но как исправить в контексте данного кода?

Comment: @МаксимСорокин, Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, почему функция принимает двойной массив, после чего заполняет его числами.. Думаю, нужно что-то такое (но это не точно):

```
static int[,] Zapolnenie()
        {
            string arrs;
            int[,] arrayInt = new int[2,2];

            Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива через пробел:");

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayInt.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                arrs = Console.ReadLine(); 
                var massiv = arrs.Split(' '); //считанные данные попадают в массив
                for(int j = 0; j<arrayInt.GetLength(1); j++) 
                    arrayInt[i, j] = int.Parse(massiv[j]); //массив записывается в тот, который вернется
            }
            return arrayInt;
        }
```

После этого вызвать метод можно вот так:

```
var massiv = Zapolnenie();
```